# Setting character encoding for all layers at once using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, pyqgis-3, encoding

I have to set the character encoding for all layers from system to UTF-8.

Is there a way to change this in all loaded layers at once?

I'm using QGIS 2.8.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following, which should set the encoding of your loaded layers to UTF-8:

### PyQGIS 3:

```py
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer.setProviderEncoding(u'UTF-8')
    layer.dataProvider().setEncoding(u'UTF-8')
    print (layer.name(), layer.dataProvider().encoding())
```

### PyQGIS 2:

```py
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer.setProviderEncoding(u'UTF-8')
    layer.dataProvider().setEncoding(u'UTF-8')
    print layer.name(), layer.dataProvider().encoding()   #Optional check: prints layer name and its encoding source
```

Remember to save your project file (*.qgs*) afterwards.

As suggested by @meles, you can input the above code into the Python Console (`Plugins > Python Console`; `Extensions > Python Console`; (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)).

Comment: That did the trick. Maybe you could mention in your answer that you have to insert the commands in Extension->Python console (Ctrl + Alt + P). That might help other people comming by. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @meles - Awesome buddy and your most welcome, glad you got it working! I've edited the post thanks to your suggestion =)

Comment: @Joseph thanks for sharing what is the difference b.w setProviderEncoding and dataProvider().setEncoding(u'UTF-8')

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan - Good question! From the API, [setProviderEncoding()](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a67fb51e8089ad9acdc396572e6a42e54) sets the text encoding of the data provider; [dataProvider().setEncoding()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#a95754bf8354a0208dcb43809e2c85042) sets the encoding used for accessing data from layer. As this was more than a year ago, my guess is they were both required for the data to be encoded and for QGIS to read the encoded data but I can't remember!