# Get all data source encoding list

Tags: pyqgis, encoding

I am able to set data source encoding through [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152546/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-character-encoding-for-all-layers-at-once) to [Setting character encoding for all layers at once using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152546/setting-character-encoding-for-all-layers-at-once-using-pyqgis) and now i want to list all the datasource encodig types. how it is possible i have also check official [API](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html) but nothing found!

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer.setProviderEncoding(u'UTF-8')
    layer.dataProvider().setEncoding(u'UTF-8')
    print layer.name(), layer.dataProvider().encoding()
```

Comment: You want to list all encoding types from your layers or all encoding types available in QGIS?

Comment: i want to get both

Answer (score 3):

The [QgsVectorDataProvider](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html) class has the [availableEncodings()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#a1628f61b192992e893ba7919da66049b) method which provides you with a list of available encoding types:

```
QgsVectorDataProvider.availableEncodings()
```