# Changing QGIS 3 default encoding

Tags: qgis, encoding

When I import shapefile layers their encoding is System while the data is in UTF-8.

How to change the default encoding to UTF-8?

This question answer here "
[Is it possible to change default encoding for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238182/is-it-possible-to-change-default-encoding-for-qgis)
" is no longer valid since in QGIS 3.12.3 there is no longer such option available in Data Sources.

Comment: Have you tried to add .cpg file? It is a plain text file that contains only the codepage id, for utf-8 `UTF-8`.

Comment: Or you can try to set the environmental variable `SHAPE_ENCODING=UTF-8` https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#SHAPE_ENCODING but it seems that it would be applied to all shapefiles even if they were not UTF-8.

Comment: You can also use the Python script provided here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152551/107424 to change all layer encodings at once.

Comment: Thanks! The Python script solved my problem.