# Converting shapefile with Windows-1252 encoding to UTF-8 for QField

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qfield, encoding, qfieldsync

When packaging a QGIS project for QField using QFieldSync plugin, I get the following error:

> Layer does not use UTF-8, but "windows-1252" encoding.Working with layers that do not use UTF-8 encoding might cause problems.It is highly recommended to convert them to UTF-8 encoded layers.

The file is then unavailable when opening the project in QField.

How do I convert the shapefile to UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: This was stopping me configuring projects for QField using QGIS 3.22 and QField 2.14, both via QFieldCloud and via cable. The problem has gone away now I have encoded the shp files at UTF-8.

Comment: There was this thread on the default encoding setting.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381308/how-to-change-qgis-3-default-encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the layer - Export as, and specify the encoding